# First eigenvalue in Ricci flow.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the picture below, why is $\lambda(g_{ij})$ the first eigenvalue of $-4\Delta+R$?

The first eigenvalue is strange to me. After reading the wiki about it, I find

$$\lambda_1=\inf\limits_{u\ne 0}\frac{\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2}{\int_\Omega|u|^2}$$

where $u$ is the solution to 
$$
\begin{cases} \Delta u + \lambda u = 0 & \text{in $\Omega$} \\ \left. u\right|_{\partial \Omega} = 0 \end{cases}
$$

But seemingly, it is not the first eigenvalue in pictures 1,2  and 3. Also, why is the first eigenfunction $u_0>0$ in picture 3 bigger than $0$?

Pictures 1, 2 and 3 are from the 203rd page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Do you really need Picture 1? You could write the Dirichlet problem yourself.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi  Sorry, I don't know how to write the big $\{$

Comment: `\begin{cases} \Delta u + \lambda u = 0 & \text{in $\Omega$} \\ \left. u\right|_{\partial \Omega} = 0 \end{cases}` between double $.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi  Thanks ,I have edit it .